# Centrale and local Data base management

Tags: java, oracle

I need to create a web application that it will work in many stores and every operation in each store (add , modify , delete ...) needs to be updated in a central database to make the main office of the store to always have a look about the updated information on each store ...
note that i am using oracle db and java as server side .
what is the appropriate approach to do that ?
should be done by a database configuration ?
or its a server engine that will update both the store and the central database ?

Answer (score 0):

There a plenty of approaches that you can take to make it work. As far as I understand, you will have a local database at each store which will store the inventory available at that particular store. And all of this information will also be aggregated on a central database located in the main office or central warehouse. And you need to write a stock management tool. If this is what you need, then one of the architectures you can use to make it work might look like the following.

A central database has `Stores` and `Products` tables where the `Products` table has the following structure:

> Products (id, name, category, price, store_id, ...)

The `store_id` is a foreign key referencing `id` column of the `Stores` table. This will enable you to aggregate the data from all stores in one table. Then in the GUI of your stock management application you can just filter the store products by the store for each store.

To synchronize local and central databases you create a materialised view at local databases. According to [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28326/repmview.htm),

> A materialized view is a replica of a target master from a single
>   point in time. The master can be either a master table at a master
>   site or a master materialized view at a materialized view site.

The materialized view is often used for data replication purposes because in contrast to ordinary view it creates a copy of the data in the local database. By default, the view is not refreshed after creation, so you have to write a job to update it with new values from the central databse (for example, when the central stock changes).  But materialized views also support automatic refresh.

A materialized view `V_Products` is created as follows

> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW V_Products AS select * from
>   user.products@maindb WHERE store_id = ?

where `?` denotes the respective store_id (corresponding to the id of the store at which you create the view), `maindb` is the SID of the central database and user. More information is available in the official documentation on [materialized views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28326/repmview.htm) and CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW [statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF01302).

Local databases can be connected to the central database by using a [database link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm) which represent a

> connection between two physical database servers that allows a client
>   to access them as one logical database.

You should also consider partitioning the `Products` table in the central database by `store_id` to increase performance of your selects - among other things, it will make synchronization of data from central into local databases faster.

Comment: Thank you a lot akhilless , i will take your advice and research more on it